# How can I retrieve two entities that are associated with a connection entity, only under the name record2roleid?

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

I have a connection that connects to the two entities "workorder" and "object" with a role name [record2roleid].

How can I check the connection between the two entities if they are just under the attributename [record2roleid]?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, atleast some SQL equivalent to convert into linq..

Comment: var connections = from c in ServiceContext.CreateQuery("connection")
                                  where c.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("record2roleid").Name.Equals("x")
                                  select c;

Answer (score 0):

Try with this way

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="connection">
    <attribute name="record2id" />
    <attribute name="record2roleid" />
    <attribute name="connectionid" />
    <attribute name="record2objecttypecode" />
    <attribute name="record1objecttypecode" />
    <attribute name="record1roleid" />
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="record1id" />

    <link-entity name="connectionrole" from="connectionroleid" to="record2roleid" link-type="inner" alias="ad">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="name" operator="like" value="%Part%" />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch
```

Comment: Thank you, I have found a solution but I will try your solution later, because I also want to learn Fetch-Xml.:)

thanks again !